# Haskell HXT to parse rows and columns and getting [[String]] and not [String]

Tags: list, haskell, spreadsheet, hxt

I'm trying to use HXT to parse a ods (libreoffice spreadsheet) file and having trouble.
In a spreadsheet, a row has many cells (all with name "cell") and the spreadsheet has many rows (all with name row). 
When I try to get the text of the cells, the code mix it all together and it end up with a whole bunch of cell not separate by rows...

When trying to parse the following:

```
<spreadsheet>
    <row>
       <cell> <p>ABC</p> </cell>
       <cell> <p>DEF</p> </cell>
       <cell> <p>GHI</p> </cell>
    </row>
    <row>
       <cell> <p>abc</p> </cell>
       <cell> <p>def</p> </cell>
       <cell> <p>ghi</p> </cell>
    </row>
    <row>
       <cell> <p>123</p> </cell>
       <cell> <p>456</p> </cell>
       <cell> <p>789</p> </cell>
    </row>
</spreadsheet>
```

With the code:

```
import Text.XML.HXT.Core

play arg = do { results <- runX (processor arg) ; print results }
atTag x = getChildren >>> isElem >>> hasName x

processor filename =
    readDocument [withValidate no] filename >>>
    atTag "spreadsheet" >>>
    atTag "row" >>>
    atTag "cell" >>>
    atTag "p" >>>
    getChildren >>> getText
```

It gives [ABC, DEF, GHI, abc, def, ghi, 123, 456, 789] while what I wanted was [[ABC, DEF, GHI], [abc, def, ghi], [123, 456, 789]].

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the type of, say, `atTag`? If it is `Tree -> [Tree]` then you should be able to do `let rows = readDocument >>> ... >> atTag "row"` and then `map (\t -> t >>> atTag "cell" >>> ... >>> getText) rows` to get a satisfactory result. I've never used HXT though...

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`listA`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hxt/9.3.1.1/doc/html/Control-Arrow-ArrowList.html#v:listA) to collect results into a list at the appropriate point:

```
import System.Environment (getArgs)
import Text.XML.HXT.Core

processor filename =
  readDocument [withValidate no] filename
    />  hasName "spreadsheet"
    />  hasName "row"
    >>> listA (getChildren >>> hasName "cell" /> hasName "p" /> getText)

main = fmap head getArgs >>= runX . processor >>= print
```

This will print the result you want.

Note that I'm using the provided `/>` and `hasName` instead of your `atTag`, but you could easily translate back if you want to stick with `atTag`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not HXT, but you could use the following to solve it with [xml-conduit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-conduit):

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Text.XML
import Text.XML.Cursor
import qualified Data.Text as T

main = do
    c <- fmap fromDocument $ Text.XML.readFile def "foo.xml"
    print $ c $// element "row" >=> perRow
  where
    perRow row = [row $/ element "cell" >=> perCell]
    perCell cell = [T.strip $ T.concat $ cell $// content]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works! But Keeping question open. Still curious about how to implement it with HXT, though.